# Flutter: Update the UI with value from an async function

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I want to see a the value of a counter in a flutter UI when the counter is updated asynchronously.

Staring from the sample flutter project, I would expect the below would make it, but only the final value is displayed. How can I achieve to see the numbers changing from 1 to 100000?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() async {
    for(int i=0; i<100000; ++i) {
      setState(() {
        _counter++;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this code updates the UI as expected, do you want to have a history of past numbers ? or what do you mean by asynchronously.

Comment: A better approach would be yielding those numbers as a `Stream` and listen to it via `StreamBuilder`

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is just that your loop is running too fast to show the intermediate values. Slowing the loop down with `Future.delayed()` should let you see what you want.

```
void _incrementCounter() async {
  for(int i=0; i<100000; ++i) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*to see the numbers changing from 1 to 100000* You can use `Timer.periodic`.

Creating state level timer variable to have control on running state.

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  Timer? _timer;

  void _incrementCounter() async {
    const delay = Duration(milliseconds: 100); // controll update speed
    const numberLimit = 100000;
    _timer = Timer.periodic(delay, (timer) {
      if (_counter < numberLimit) {
        setState(() {
          _counter++;
        });
      } else {
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });
  }

  void _reset() {
    setState(() {
      _counter = 0;
    });
    _timer?.cancel();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

You can find more about  [`dart-async-library`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-async/dart-async-library.html) and [`Timer.periodic`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html) on flutter.dev.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  late Timer _timer;
  int _start = 0;

  void startTimer() {
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    _timer = new Timer.periodic(
        oneSec,
        (Timer timer) => setState(() {
              if (_start > 100000) {
                timer.cancel();
              } else {
                _start = _start + 1;
              }
            }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_start',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: startTimer,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use `ValueListenableBuilder` to notify you state instead of calling `setState` as it will `rebuild` whole ui. Read here in more details about [ValueListenableBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html)

Below is sample code -

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Timer? _timer;
  ValueNotifier _valueNotifier = ValueNotifier(0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: _valueNotifier,
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return Text(value.toString());
      },
    );
  }

  void _incrementCounter() async {
    const delay = Duration(milliseconds: 100); // controll update speed
    const numberLimit = 100000;
    _timer = Timer.periodic(delay, (timer) {
      if (_valueNotifier.value < numberLimit) {
        _valueNotifier.value++;
      } else {
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });
  }

  void _reset() {
    _valueNotifier.value = 0;
    _timer?.cancel();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
   _valueNotifier.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: I have tried that too but with the same result. At the end, the solution is to slow down the increment. That is  ok for the sample indeed, but not for a real application. I would go on the route of ignoring too frequent updates... but honestly I am giving up with Flutter